# TPIN number validation in java, c++ or c#

Tags: c#, java, c++, validation

I have small requirement for TPIN validation in my college project, The requirement is, we should not allow the user to set  his TPIN in the below scenarios .

1. TPIN should not be in sequence. (either ascending or descending ex: 123456, 456789, 987654 or 654321)
2. TPIN should not start from Zero (ex: 0127865, 098764)
3. TPIN should not be repetitive digit (ex: 888888,222222 etc.)

For the third one my idea is to divide the number by 11 and check for the reminder..

Any ideas plz..

```
public class Validate
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        int iTpin = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // Converted string to int
        System.out.println("The entered TPIN is:"+iTpin);
        boolean flag = validate(iTpin);
        if (flag== true)
            System.out.println("The entered TPIN is valid");
        else 
            System.out.println("The entered TPIN is Invalid");
    }

    public static boolean validate(int passedTpin)
    {
        if (passedTpin == 0)
            return false;
        else if ( passedTpin%11 == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Finally created code for the sequence of digits. It might be useful for others

```
private static boolean containsRepetitiveDigits(String tpin) {
    char firstChar = tpin.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < tpin.length(); i++) {
        char nextChar = tpin.charAt(i);
        if ((Character.valueOf(nextChar)).compareTo(Character
                .valueOf(firstChar)) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Error:TPIN contains repetitive digits");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When it comes to PIN codes, it usually makes more sense to deal with them as strings even if they are all numeric.

Comment: @ereOn : You are right, fed up trying with integers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For start, using `Int32` to store a number means it **shouldn't exceed [2,147,483,647](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx)**. And apart from this, you won't be able to check for the **leading zero** once you have converted to a number, since leading zeros obviously disappear once you get a number.

This means you should keep the input as a `string` during validation. This actually makes your job easier, since you can index individual characters, without the need to use arithmetic operations.

Since you are working with strings, you should also check if the input string contains invalid (non-digit) characters before anything else:

```
bool ContainsInvalidCharacters(string input)
{
    // check if there is a non-digit character
    foreach (char c in input)
        if (!char.IsDigit(c))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Then you can continue adding individual rules. For example, to check if characters are repeating, you will do something like:

```
bool ContainsRepetitiveDigits(string input)
{
    if (input.Length == 0)
        return false;

    // get the first character
    char firstChar = input[0];

    // check if there is a different character
    foreach (char c in input)
        if (c != firstChar)
            return false;

    // if not, it means it's repetitive
    return true;
}

bool StartsWithZero(string input)
{
    if (input.Length == 0)
        return false;

    return (input[0] == '0');
}
```

To detect sequences, the most straightforward way is to get the difference of first two characters, and then check if it changes through the entire string:

```
bool IsSequence(string input)
{
    // we need at least two characters
    // for a sequence
    if (input.Length < 2)
        return false;

    // get the "delta" between first two
    // characters
    int difference = input[1] - input[0];

    // allowed differences are:
    //   -1: descending sequence
    //    0: repetitive digits
    //    1: ascending sequence
    if (difference < -1 || difference > 1)
        return false;

    // check if all characters are equally
    // distributed
    for (int i = 2; i < input.Length; i++)
        if (input[i] - input[i - 1] != difference)
            return false;

    // this is a sequence
    return true;
}
```

Once you've defined all of your rules, you can create a single method which will test them one by one:

```
bool Validate(string input)
{
    // list of all predicates to check
    IEnumerable<Predicate<string>> rules = new Predicate<string>[]
    {
        ContainsInvalidCharacters,
        ContainsRepetitiveDigits,
        StartsWithZero,
        IsSequence
    };

    // check if any rule matches
    foreach (Predicate<string> check in rules)
        if (check(input))
            return false;

    // if no match, it means input is valid
    return true;
}
```

Note that `IsSequence` detects repetitive digit patterns also (when character difference is zero). If you want to explicitly prevent this, alter the condition where allowed differences are checked. Alternatively, you can remove the `ContainsRepetitiveDigits` rule altogether.

---

**[Edit]**

Since I see you are using Java instead of C#, I will try to provide a better example.

**Disclaimer:** I don't usually program in Java, but from what I know, Java doesn't support delegates the way C# does. So I will try to provide a Java example (hope it will work), which expresses my "composite validation" intent better.

**(Suspicious Java code follows)**

First, define an interface which all validation rules will implement:

```
// (java code)
/**
 * Defines a validation rule.
 */
public interface IValidationRule
{
    /**
     * Returns a description of this
     * validation rule.
     */
    String getDescription();

    /**
     * Returns true if this rule
     * is matched.
     */
    boolean matches(String tpin);
}
```

Next, define each rule in a separate class, implementing both `getDescription` and `matches` methods:

```
// (java code)
public class RepetitiveDigitsRule implements IValidationRule
{
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return "TPIN contains repetitive digits";
    }

    public boolean matches(String tpin)
    {
        char firstChar = tpin.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < tpin.length(); i++)
            if (tpin.charAt(i) != firstChar)
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}

public class StartsWithZeroRule implements IValidationRule
{
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return "TPIN starts with zero";
    }

    public boolean matches(String tpin)
    {
        if (tpin.length() < 1)
            return false;

        return tpin.charAt(0) == '0';
    }
}
```

You can see that `matches` method does **not** print anything to console. It simply returns `true` if rule is matched, and leaves to its **caller** to decide whether to print its description (to console, a message box, web page, whatever).

Finally, you can instantiate all known rules (implementations of `IValidationRule`) and check them one by one:

```
// (java code)
public class Validator
{
    // instantiate all known rules
    IValidationRule[] rules = new IValidationRule[] {
        new RepetitiveDigitsRule(),
        new StartsWithZeroRule()
    };

    // validate tpin using all known rules
    public boolean validate(String tpin)
    {
        System.out.print("Validating TPIN " + tpin + "... ");

        // for all known rules
        for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++)
        {
            IValidationRule rule = rules[i];

            // if rule is matched?
            if (rule.matches(tpin))
            {
                // print rule description
                System.out.println("Error: " + rule.getDescription());
                return false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Success.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

I recommend trying to follow this pattern. You will end up with code much easier to reuse and maintain.

Comment: @Groo : One last thing left , to check for the rule number 1.. 1. TPIN should not be in sequence.

Comment: @Groo : Can you please tell me how to check for sequence digits?

Comment: @Chandu: I thought I posted enough to get you going. :) Ok, I will update the answer, although I suggest you try to do it yourself anyway.

Comment: @Groo : Thanks.. i edited my question and added the my own answer for sequence checking, let me know if it can be made better :)

Comment: @Chandu: I am no java expert, but I believe you don't need `Character.valueOf`, you can simply write `if (tpin.charAt(i) != firstChar) return false`.

Comment: @Chandu: I also recommend separating your validation logic from printing messages to console. I will update my answer with java-specific example.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate sequetial tpin (ascending & decending) based on the first digit then compare it to the inputted tpin. If it matches then it is invalid.

```
public static bool IsSequential(string pin, bool descending)
{
    int p = Convert.ToInt32(pin.Substring(0,1));
    string tpin = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        tpin += descending ? (p--).ToString() : (p++).ToString();
    }
    return pin.Equals(tpin);          
}
```

For item 3, you cannot just divide by 11 because some pin will have remainder 0. (i.e. 221199 is a valid one but the remainder is 0). You can get the first digit and use a loop to compare to the remaining digits.

Comment: it seems that its easier in C#